# buttons showing (null) when clicked, even when disabled

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have some buttons on my storyboard that I removed all text from and which I later add text to programmatically, so when the application starts the buttons are invisible. However, if a user clicks any **one** of the buttons, all **four** of the buttons show `(null)` in the label section of the button. I thought this might be because the buttons were enabled, so I added this code in the `initWithFrame` method of the subclass of UIView where the buttons are a property however it didn't change anything.

Furthermore, I don't understand why clicking one of the buttons would show (null) in the label area of all four buttons.

```
 - (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];

    if (self) {
        // Initialization code
        self.button1.enabled= NO;
        self.button2.enabled= NO;
        self.button3.enabled= NO;
        self.button4.enabled= NO;


    }
    return self;
}
```

I then considered that maybe this `initWithFrame` method isn't getting run when I thought it was. I tried in the subview of UIView and didn't change result

```
-(id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder {
    if (self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder]) {

        self.answerChoice1.enabled= NO;
        self.answerChoice2.enabled= NO;
        self.answerChoice3.enabled= NO;
        self.answerChoice4.enabled= NO;
    }
    return self;
}
```

Can you explain why all four buttons are showing (null) if I click on any one of them?

Comment: Try with `initWithCoder`.

Comment: @Larme thanks, but didn't work (see update)

Comment: Why aren't you using the `hidden` property to hide the buttons? Irrespective, without seeing how you're setting the label it's impossible to tell why the button label is being set as you describe.

Comment: First, check if buttons outlets and actions are not connected to the same property. Someone correct me if i'm wrong, but i think If they're IBOutlets, they're initialized when the view is loaded, so you can start work on them in `viewDidLoad` or "later". In all `init`-like methods they will be `nil`.

Comment: @BiWoj this is a subclass of UIView and therefore doesn't have viewDidLoad

Comment: @middaparka ok that worked if you write an answer (mentioning that I should hide the buttons in awakefromNib method) then I will accept it, otherwise I'll add that answer later

Comment: To be honest, there's little value in adding an answer to that extent (which is why I added it as a comment), as it's really addressing a different issue than the one your question raises. (i.e.: There's still a problem, hiding the buttons is just obscuring it.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it depends i think on the selector the button is calling, and also whether you are able to distinguish your buttons.

you can use button.tag property to distinguish between your buttons as below:

```
    // declare and allocate
    UIButton* button1 = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
    // set frame
    button1.frame = frameButton1;
    // add to view
    [self.view addSubview: button1];

    // properties from docs
    // button1.enabled or button1.hidden or button1 setTitle.. here

    // add selector
    [button1 addTarget:self selector:@selector(buttonAction:) ..UIEventTouchUpInside];

    // add identifier, integer in this case
    button1.tag = 1;

    // repeat for other buttons


    // in your selector
    - (void)buttonAction:(UIButton *)sender
    {
        // identify button
        switch (sender.tag) {
            case 0:
                // perform action
                [self doAction];
                break;

                //..
        }

        // perform shared actions

    }
```